# estimates of $c_k$ in $\left|\frac{\zeta^{(k)}}{\zeta} (1+it)\right| \le c_k Y^k(t)$

Tags: riemann-zeta-function

By the Vinogradov-Korobov estimate we have

$\left|\frac{\zeta^{(k)}}{\zeta} (1+it)\right| \le c_k Y^k(t)$ where $Y(t)= \ln^{2/3} (|t|+3) (\ln\ln (|t|+3))^{1//3}$ for some $c_k$.

I search the value of $c_k$ without the Riemann hypothesis or other hypothesis **in the litterature**.

Can you help me ?

Comment: You may want to spend some time improving your question.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I search in the litterature.